# Lifting one's eyes during Kedusha

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, kedusha-prayer

What is the source for lifting one's eyes heavenwards when reciting "kadosh, kadosh, kadosh" during the Kedusha?

Comment: From where do you know that such a practice exists?

Comment: Some people rise up on their toes during "kadosh, kadosh kadosh..."

Comment: http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/lifting-the-eyes-during-kedusha/#ftn6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source is from the tannaitic work [Pirkei Hechalot Rabbati](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hekhalot_literature) ([11:1](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/merkava/hechalot_rabati.htm)), cited in MB ([125:5](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%94)) where Rema simply says one should lift his eyes during the kedushah.